# ... which is your treat

Tags: sentence-structure

I am going to write down several equivalent ways of saying "treat you to something".

(1) Yesterday, John treated me to lunch.

(2) Yesterday, John bought me lunch.

(3) Yesterday, John and I had lunch. It was his treat.

(4) Yesterday, John and I had lunch - his treat.

(5) Yesterday, John and I had lunch, **which was his treat**.

Grammatically, I am pretty sure that (1) to (4) have no problem. Does (5) make sense?

Comment: (5) is just another way of saying (3) and is perfectly fine; however it can sound a little different where it could be a treat for John.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, to prevent misunderstanding you could add **to me** on the end.  **Yesterday, John and I had lunch, which was his treat to me**

Comment: @Chris - I wouldn't characterize #5 as "perfectly fine" because I think it sounds a bit more awkward than the other four.

Comment: @J.R. - It may sound awkward to you and some others but it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Chris there are a lot of "grammatically perfect" sentences that would never actually be used in real English...

Comment: @Chris - Had you said "grammatically correct," I wouldn't have left a comment. Instead, you said "perfectly fine," which to me sounds _better_ than grammatically correct – or, at least, some learners might be led to believe so.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are correct and understandable.

#5 is very similar to #3 except it is a compound sentence.